# Divide number without losing value

Tags: python

I have below code

```
number = 10
for i in range(3):
    print(round(10/3,2))
```

The output is

```
3.33
3.33
3.33
```

But I need output like

```
3.33
3.33
3.34
```

**I want to add rest for last item.**

I can do like dividing one less time, then subtract the total divided value from original, but I am looking is there anything inbuilt.

**I have to do this for a range of columns**

How can I get that..
Thanks,

Comment: You're doing the same calculation `10/3` three times. Why would you assume the result would change?

Comment: Are you mixing decimal separator (`.` in Python, but `,` in some European languages) with tuple notation (`,` in Python)?

Comment: I Assume he wants to divide 10 by 3 and add the Modulo to the last third so that no rest is left.

Comment: @MrIrrelevantm yes that;s correct

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have assumed that it give 3.34, subtracting previous two 3.33 from 10. It is not so. To get the desired result:

```
number = 10
N = 0
for i in range(3):
    if i != 2 :
        n = round(number/3,2)
        N = N + n
        print(n)
    else :
        print(number-N)

'''Output:
3.33
3.33
3.34
'''
```

Comment: This will tend to break in certain cases. Floating point math is not reliable for this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Yes, This problem is there in python. But as it is only 2 digits after decimal, there should not be any errors I guess. I checked with few values after seeing your comment.

Comment: This is just an example, I have a range of columns where I need to do this. number =10 is just a column

Comment: Python does not have a concept of "columns". If you are asking about Pandas (or Numpy, or Polars, or some other third-party library) you should include details about that. Probably (accept this answer, or post one of your own which answers the question you actually asked, and) post a new question with your actual requirements, and enough background. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].